# Notepad++ RegEx Replace "="

Tags: regex, jmeter, notepad++, jmx

I have alot of nodes with different values like the following within an XML of an JMeter file:

> HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="/ams/auth/elba/wizard2?lang=de&frid=afb8764b-cd83-44db-ab12-68ed1a72e0b0" enabled="true">
>
> stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/ams/auth/elba/wizard2?lang=de&frid=afb8764b-cd83-44db-ab12-68ed1a72e0b0/stringProp>

To be replaced is every "= or & or ? or %" but only if its written after testname and not if there is

I'm using Notepad++ but any other solution

Comment: Do you mean replace the value between double quote as `"/ams/auth/elba/wizard2?lang=de&frid=afb8764b-cd83-44db-ab12-68ed1a72e0b0"` in your example?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to remove only those characters, I guess you could use the following regex in a loop until the regex is no longer able to match anything (I don't think it is possible to what you want in a single operation). The regex can do the replacement in all the "testname=" in the text file at once, but can only remove one illegal character in the URL at the time.

```
/(testname="[^=&?%]+?)([=&?%])(.+?")/
```

and replace with `$1$3`

1. **capture group 1**: `(testname="[^=&?%]+?)`. It match the literal text testname=" and match all the characters not in the group `[^=&?%]` 0 or more time (the plus) as few time as possible (the question mark means non-greedy).
2. **capture group 2**: `([=&?%])` Capture one and only one character in the group (one of the characters you want to remove).
3. **capture group 3**: `(.+?")` Match any character (the dot) one or more time (the plus) as few time as possible (the question mark). Basically match everything until you reach the first double quote.

You should know that those characters are used to delimiter the parameters (question mark for the first parameter and ampersand for the others) and assign a value to a parameter (the equal sign) if you want to pass parameters by GET in a URL.

If you remove only those characters, you URL will no longer be a valid one. Maybe what you are really looking is to remove all the parameters in the URL. In that case you can use that regex in a single operation:

```
/(testname=".*?)\?.*?"/
```

Basically, you want to match everything up to the first question mark (which indicates the first parameter in the URL) in the capture group. Then, you grab the question mark along with everything until you reach the first double quote.

Use that as the replacement `$1"`